# Customizar link em um html email

Tags: css

Estou preparando um html e quero customizar o link com o evento hover, mas não obtive sucesso.

```
<a href="http://www.teste.com/" target="_blank" style="color:#929292; text-decoration: none; display: block;">Acessar</a>
```

Comment: Se é para um email, parece que neste momento não tem solução mesmo. [Veja esta questão relacionada no SOen](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1033156/how-to-write-ahover-in-inline-css)

Comment: A maioria dos clientes de e-mail não reconhecem a tag `<style>` já o `:hover` vc não é possível de fazer direto inline na tag

Answer (score 0):

Basta adicionar a seguinte regra no css do seu html:

```
a:hover {
    // aqui vai a customização desejada
}
```

**Edição:** Não existe uma forma de aplica esta regra inline, mas para casos de html de email que tudo prescisa estar no mesmo arquivo você pode colocar o css dentro das tags `<style>` dentro do seu `<body>`

Comment: Humberto, o css é inline, pois é um html email. Tentei inserir do mesmo jeito o css usando a:hover e não funcionou.

Comment: Editei a resposta para cobrir o seu caso do email

Comment: Não cobriu amigo, nenhum cliente de e-mail reconhece a tag body, e um ou outro aceita a tad style, o Outlook e o Gmail mesno não aceitam

Comment: Tem alguns bons anos que eu uso o template de email desta forma e nunca tive problemas de não ser reconhecido, mesmo no outlook. O que pode ocorre é um estilo próprio do seu leitor de email estar sobrescrevendo o estilo que você escreveu, neste caso você pode usar o atributo `!important` para forçar este estilo, embora eu não recomende forçar o estilo.
Porquê se alguém está usando um estilo customizado tem algum motivo, as vezes por questões de acessibilidade...